# How do I get text to Marquee in the Android-wheel?

Tags: android, marquee

I am using the android-wheel http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/ in an application.

I have three of the wheels side by side on my screen.  When the text in a wheel is wider than the wheel I would like it to scroll to the side (As per Marquee)

I have implemented an `AbstractWheelTextAdapter` and created a custom `ScrollingTextView` for the items as follows:  (`ScrollingTextView` is to overcome the issue with Marquee only working when an item has focus)

```
public class ScrollingTextView extends TextView {


public ScrollingTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {

    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

}



public ScrollingTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

    super(context, attrs);

}



public ScrollingTextView(Context context) {

    super(context);

}

@Override

protected void onFocusChanged(boolean focused, int direction, Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {

    if(focused)

        super.onFocusChanged(focused, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);

}

@Override

public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean focused) {

    if(focused)

        super.onWindowFocusChanged(focused);

}

@Override

public boolean isFocused() {

    return true;

}
```

}

And the xml:

```
<com.test.app.ScrollingTextView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id = "@+id/wheel_text"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:inputType="text"
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
android:textColor="#F000"
android:lines="1"
android:focusable="true"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>
```

Has anyone been able to get this to work?

(I have also tried setting the **Ellipse** in the code for the `AbstractWheelTextAdapter` without success)

Answer (score 0):

Because the WheelView didn't invalidate itself.In Activity,add the code :

```
Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        wheelview.invalidate();
        sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 0);
        }
};  
handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
```

Then the TextView Marquee effect works.But when you scroll the WheelView,the TextView string reset from start.

I had try the TextView Marquee effect in ListView, the Marquee effect works.I gonna check the ListView source code ,see what differences between ListView and WheelView.